# Core Data supplied doc at startup

Tags: cocoa

Thanks for the help.

Core Data doc based app/sqlite format.

A few things I know I can do:

Running the app for the first time displays an "untitled" document. I can add data, save, and subsequently run the previously saved document at startup with additional code. No problem with this. It's all working.

What I need to do is supply a previously created sqlite file that contains data and have the application immediately run it at startup, bypassing the display of an "untitled" document.

I'm set with sending the sqlite file located in my application bundle to ~/Library/Application Support/Some App/dbase.sqlite. How do I set things up so that upon launch - this default document runs at startup?

I'm doing it this way to make things easy for the user: choosing the supplied database - or the option to create custom docs stored in different locations, if necessary.

Thanks again.

Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `NSApplication` delegate, you should implement the `‑applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:` delegate method and return `NO`. This will prevent the app from creating a new, untitled document at launch.

You should then implement the `‑applicationDidFinishLaunching:` delegate method which is called once the app has finished loading. In your implementation you should call the `‑makeDocumentWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:` method of `NSDocumentController` to open the file you wish to display.

You can get an instance of the document controller with:

```
[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController]
```

You can get the URL for your document using:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourDocName" ofType:@"YourDocFileExtension"];
```

Comment: Hey, Robb -thanks again. I have everything sorted out except this: ‑makeDocumentWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error: ... I'm working on it.